# Set button titles programmatically in an array

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, button

I have an array of expandable buttons that all hold the same title "Open". I would like for each button to have their own respective name since they will all hold their own features. How would I go about setting each of the button titles to something unique? Would I have to build each button on their own and step away from the expandable array?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle("Open", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleExpandClose), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.tag = section
    return button

}
 var showIndexPaths = true
@objc func handleExpandClose(button: UIButton) {

    print("trying to expand and close section")

    print(button.tag)
    let section = button.tag
    var indexPaths = [IndexPath]()

    button.setTitle(isExpanded ? "Open" : "Close", for: .normal)
    if isExpanded {
        tableView.deleteRows(at: indexPaths, with: .fade)
    }else{
        tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .fade)
    }
   }
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 40
}

}
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if !twodimensionalArray[section].isExpanded {
        return 0
    }
     return twodimensionalArray[section].list.count
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)


    return cell
}
}
```

I will post a picture as well to describe. 
[image]

Comment: what is expandable button ?

Comment: Setup the button title just like the rest of your cell in `cellForRowAt`.

Comment: Yes. As long as you hold on to that array. You rename the button title using setTitle: for state method

Comment: @RatulSharker an expandable button is a button when clicked on expands to show more information instead of switching to another view.

Comment: @rmaddy I have a list of buttons in the same view and they all of the same names. How would I go about setting their titles differently?

Comment: @zachwilcox You need to update your question with relevant code. Clearly show what you have, what you've tried, and what help you need.

Comment: @rmaddy I have updated my question here. I have tried a few more methods that I have researched since asking this question, however, none of them has worked for me. I either get error codes or I create a new button when I just want to rename each of these.

Comment: please update your code, by means updating your code is not just throwing some codes, from where they called, i.e here are some function body without any function declaration, it even return a button. who recieved it ? what heppens next ? show relevant code section not creation, where you add this button as subview ? these sort of stuffs.

Comment: @RatulSharker I updated my code above with all of the relevant code that related to the expandable buttons. I hope this better assist you! thank you in advance.

Comment: Hello @zachwilcox ; this looks like a great opportunity to use custom (subclassed) table view cells.  [Here is a tutorial that shows you how to do this](https://www.ralfebert.de/ios-examples/uikit/uitableviewcontroller/custom-cells/), [and another](https://medium.com/programming-with-swift/create-a-custom-uitableviewcell-with-swift-6d7eb7389f19).  In the meantime, could you update your example code above to show if your table view is connected to an `@IBOutlet` (is it in a storyboard or xib file), or did you create the table programatically?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I created this programmatically!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step #1**

According to your last update, let you have a title array in your viewController

```
class YourViewController: UITableViewController { // as you marked the tableview delegate and datasource as override so your view controller should be subclass of UITableViewController
    let btnTitles = [
        "Open",
        "Close",
        "Action1",
        ...
    ]


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    // although it's not quiet right creating button each time this section header view is prompted. You can cache these buttons with indexPath key, then try to get that button while the delegate asks for it, if not present than create it otherwise just reuse the returned button. But for this example it will work fine.
          let button = UIButton(type: .system)
          button.setTitle(btnTitles[section], for: .normal)
          button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
          button.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
          button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
          button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleExpandClose), for: .touchUpInside)
          button.tag = section
         return button

    }
}
```

**Step #2**

These setup will give you what you want. You didn't share the `numberOfRowsInSection` method. Which should return the `count` of `btnTitles`.